# Magento 2.3 stock update in DB level

Tags: magento2.3, manage-stock

I'm Currently using magento2.3, i have added a cron job to update products stock every 20 min from external inventory which will create a CSV file to magento directory, i will read this file and loop
to the quantity and create a SQL query to update it to **cataloginventory_stock_item** table and run reindex.

Quantity get updated but not showing add to cart in front-end , after product save manually from admin it's working fine. It is proper method to update qty or else there is any other method for performance using this method, because our store having more then 20K+ products

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below code if it helps instead of updating the stock directly to the database table.

Use the `Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface` to update the product qty.

```
public function updateQty($qty,$sku) {
    $stockItem = $stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
    $stockItem->setQty($qty);
    $stockItem->setIsInStock((bool)$qty);
    $stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
}
```

OR try the below sql query for update stock:

```
UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_item item_stock, cataloginventory_stock_status status_stock
SET item_stock.qty = '$qty', item_stock.is_in_stock = IF('$qty'>0, 1,0),
status_stock.qty = '$qty', status_stock.stock_status = IF('$qty'>0, 1,0)
WHERE item_stock.product_id = '$product_id' AND item_stock.product_id = status_stock.product_id
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for you help, As i previously mentioned i'm having 20k+ products, each 20 min cron will run for 20k+ products
so performance will affect if i'm using this method ?

Comment: Do you set is_in_stock = 1 ? Like UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_item SET qty = 100, is_in_stock = 1 WHERE product_id = ID.

Comment: Yes i am setting is_in_stock = 1 also by checking condition if qty greater than 0 and after reindex cataloginventory_stock_status table also get updated

Comment: Have you tried flushing the cache after the update in database table?

Comment: Yes i have but no use

Comment: Magento also saves the stock information in table `cataloginventory_stock_status`. Please try to update it along with `cataloginventory_stock_item`. See if it works!

Comment: Check the updated answer with the database query if it helps.

Comment: The value which i update in cataloginventory_stock_item after reindex it update to cataloginventory_stock_status table also . But inventory_source_item remain same with old data, i'm not sure what is the use this. Why magento2.3 stock is too complicated

Comment: Seems like you also need to update the `inventory_source_item` if source assigned.

Comment: Okay thanks i will try and let you know, it there any other better solution to update stock efficiently.